Examples showing that Moreras theorem is not applicable if we drop continuity hypothesis.
In the following picture,

two functions $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are defined and Author directly writes that, $\int_C f(z) dz=0$ for every simple closed contour in the disk with center $1$ and radius $r$ i. e. in $\triangle (1,r)$. However, $f$ is not analytic for $z\in\triangle (1, r)$, since $f$ is not even continuous at $z=1$
Similarly, on the next page of the picture, he writes that, $\int_C g(z) dz=0$ for every simple closed curve $C$ in the unit disk $\triangle (0,1)$. But $g$ is not analytic in $\triangle(0, 1) $, since $g$ is not continuous at $z=0$.
My problem is, I am not able to show that $\int_C f(z) dz=0$ for every simple closed contour $C$ in $\triangle (1, r)$ and $\int_C g(z) dz=0$ for every simple closed curve $C$ in the unit disk $\triangle (0,1)$
My attempt: We can't use any theorems like cauchy theorem or cauchy integral formula to evaluate these integral because, they require that function shoud be analytic inside and on the curve. (So how author, get that two integrals evaluates to zero? )
Moreover, I checked for continuity of $f$ at $z=1$ by myself. When $f(z)$ approaches to $z=1$ along x-axis then limit of $f(z)$ as $z\rightarrow 1$ does not exists! and hence $f$ is not continuous at $z=1$. Is am I correct?
and for $g$. Clearly limit of $g(z) $ as, $z\rightarrow 0$ does not exists. Hence, $g$ is not continuous at $z=0$ am I correct?

What book is this from? These wrong examples are particularly embarrassing because actual examples are much easier: Just take any analytic function and redefine them at an arbitrarily chosen point. Like $f(z)=\begin{cases} z \text{ if } z\neq 3 \ 17 \text{ if } z=3 \end{cases}$.

@TorstenSchoeneberg sir yes I can see the function $f(z)$ you gave is not continuous at $z=3$ and hence can't be analytic. But, is the integral of $f(z)$ along any closed contour $C$ is zero?

Yes, because changing a function value at one point (or finitely many points, or I guess any set of measure 0) does not change the value of any integral over that function. And if $f(3)$ were $3$ instead, the function would be analytic, and so ...

You are correct, these functions have singularities (poles) at $z=1$ and $z=0$ respectively.  To handle their integrals, you want to use the
Residue Theorem: the residues at those singularities are in fact $0$.
So the integral around any closed contour that does not pass through the singular point is $0$.
However, the book is wrong if it claims (as it appears to do) that $\int_C f(z) \; dz = 0$ for every simple closed contour $C$ in $\Delta(1;r)$, because in the case of a simple closed contour $C$ that passes through the singular point $z=1$, $\int_C f(z)\; dz$ is undefined.  It is certainly not a Riemann integral, and even as an improper integral it does not converge.

Sir, first of all thank for the answer. Sir can you please show that, how to calculate residue of $f(z)$ at $z=1$. Further, Is am I correct about continuity part?

$Res f(z)$ at $z=1$ is $\lim_{z\rightarrow 1}\frac{d}{dz}((z-1)^2 \frac{1}{(z-1)^2})$ hence it is, equal to $\lim_{z\rightarrow 1}\frac{d}{dz} {1}= 0$ am I correct sir?

Yes, that's one way to do it.

Sir, is there is any other way? If yes, then please can you do it for just one singularity say $z=1$. This will help me a lot.

Sir, is there any easier approach for continuity part? Is my approach for continuity part is wrong?
